# how can i reduce waiting time of http Response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, http

While searching tips to speed up the performance one [site](http://www.decossoftdev.com/insight/blog/2013/02/04/ASPNET-Website-Performance-Improvement) suggest me that **Reduce number of HTTP request :** *With the help of Firebug, Firefox extension, you can find out how many resource requests are made by your asp.net web page.  It is very important to reduce the number of HTTP requests on your server; it will help in reducing the server load and allow more visitors to access your website.*

As per this i check my site and noticed that : it need to wait a long time for `http Response` [image]

**How can i reduce this time to speedup the performance**

Comment: It's good to see the code that generating your page.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason could be some expensive operation in one of your events of the page load process. You need to optimize. To confirm, you can create a datetime variable in Page_PreInit and you can check the total processing time taken in the PagePrerender.

Most of the time, the database call will be the culprit.